# How to find number of paths between two vertices (a1,b1), (a2,b2) on a rectangular grid in Octave?

Tags: octave

In the image shown, number of possible routes should be calculated (for example: between (0,0) and (4,3)). Condition: no diagonal direction

[image]

I have tried this using adjacency matrix and digraph in MATALB, but I require output in Octave where digraph is not supported. Please suggest.

I actually have 8 possible ways to move between any two points:

1. Down, left
2. Down, right
3. Up, left
4. Up, right
5. Right, up
6. Right, down
7. Left, up
8. Left, down

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Make grid points.
x = -1:6;
y = -1:5;
[xx, yy] = meshgrid(x, y, indexing = 'ij');
G = plot(xx(:),yy(:), 'b.');
grid on;
drawnow;

%%%%%%%%%% Set up figure properties: Enlarge figure to full screen.
set(gcf, 'Units', 'Normalized', 'OuterPosition', [0, 0, 1, 1]);

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Get rid of tool bar and pulldown menus that are along top of figure.
set(gcf, 'Toolbar', 'none', 'Menu', 'none');

%%%%%%%%%%% Give a name to the title bar.

set(gcf, 'Name', 'Mega Constellation:Geographical separation', 'NumberTitle', 'Off'); 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Print (x,y) values at each point.
for k = 1 : numel(xx)
    str = sprintf('(%i, %i)', xx(k), yy(k));
    text(xx(k), yy(k), str);
end
```

Comment: What are the other restrictions on movement? Can you move in all 4 directions? If so, can you move in cycles? If so, this would create infinitely many paths. If you can only move in 2 directions (eg left and up) you can use Pascal's triangle i.e. the number of paths to `(4, 3)` is `(4+3)!/(4!3!)`. PS. to input code use the backtick symbol (\`) (which is on the "tilde" key for me), not the apostrophe symbol (').

Comment: Can you please show your MATLAB code as well? All the present code does is generate an image, but it doesn't calculate any distances. Your presented movements allow only for movement to diagonal elements. Isn't a simple up/down/left/right, i.e. travelling only a single vertex, allowed?

Comment: Posting this as a comment as I haven't touched Octave in > 10 years. There are probably multiple algorithms you could choose from. If this is an assignment you should state that as well as the algorithms covered on your course to get more accurate answers. One option is to look at it as a graph problem and use [BFS](https://github.com/aeolianine/octave-networks-toolbox/blob/master/BFS.m) or [DFS](https://github.com/aeolianine/octave-networks-toolbox/blob/master/DFS.m). Another thing too look into is Manhattan distance (or block distance)...

Comment: ...It's interesting the challenge all possible routes, not the one shortest route. It could be a really fun visual exercise as well where you can start simple on pen and paper and start tracing all paths. As you do, you'll build intuition and pickup patterns/make connections such as the difference between the end start coordinates/the number or rows/column between etc.  You can then start coding a simple to understand (not necessarily computationally efficient method) implementation which you can iterate on.

Comment: ...It's also interesting you can't move up,down,left or right in one instruction, but need to group two orthogonal steps in one move instruction. If there is no constraint on finding short path(s), in theory you could start at (0,0) go all the way to (7,6) and back to (4,3): would that be a valid path ?

Comment: I can only move up, down, left, right and only in two steps but not diagonal. Also zig-zag paths are not allowed. For example: to move from (0,0) to (4,3) one correct path is : (0,0) -->(1,0) -->(2,0) -->(3,0) -->(4,0) -->(4,1) -->(4,2) -->(4,3) 

Wrong path(zig-zag): (0,0) -->(0,1) -->(1,1) -->(2,1) -->(3,1) -->(4,1) -->(4,2) -->(4,3)